# Как убрать автоматическое заполнение src в теге img?

Tags: wordpress

При добавлении изображения на сайт, автоматически заполняется  src="". Как решить данный вопрос? Спасибо.
Хочу добавить миниатюру, получаю ее url:

```
<img src="<?php echo $thumbnail_attributes[0]; ?>" alt="" class="blog-images" />
```

А получается вот так:

```
<img src="http://localhost/aestetic/wp-content/themes/theme_1/http://localhost/aestetic/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/blog1_1-300x204.png" alt="" class="blog-images">
```

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать функцию

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'thumbnail' );
```

Для получения сразу объекта картинки.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Решил вопрос уже, виною был сторонний js скрипт.